# Allow Two Instances of Application to Run

Tags: c#

I understand how to force a single instance of an application using a mutex and this is what I use.

Several of my users have asked me to allow multiple instances to run.  I don't want to remove the control code as I can see it as a recipe for disaster since multiple instances could be writing to the same files, log and so on.

I perhaps could handle things if the number of instances is limited to two.  My current idea is to allow the first one to run as the active one and a second in some form of read-only mode.

So how would I control the number of instances to no more than two?

Thanks

Comment: You can have two mutex!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool IsFree = false;


Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MutexValue1", out IsFree);

if(!IsFree)
    mutex = new Mutex(true, "MutexValue2", out IsFree);

if(!IsFree)
{
    //two instances are already running
}
```

Comment: If you create two instances and you close the second one, another instance can be created. But if you create two instances and you close the first one, another instance can't be created. Only the semaphore solution works.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you want a named system [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt3k0k2h.aspx) with a count of 2.

Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    private const int MaxInstanceCount = 2;
    private static readonly Semaphore Semaphore = new Semaphore(MaxInstanceCount, MaxInstanceCount, "CanRunTwice");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        if (Semaphore.WaitOne(1000))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Program is running");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                Semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I cannot run, too many instances are already running");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

A Semaphore allows a number of concurrent threads to access a resource, and when it is created with a name, it is a operating-system-wide semaphore, so it fits your purpose well.

Comment: I am going to look into Semaphores.  Thank you